# Image size doesn't match the canvas size

Tags: html, canvas, png

I made canvas like this ,

```
<canvas id="mainCanvas" style="width:310px;height:212px;">
</canvas>
```

then try to put png on the canvas in my script

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var img= new Image();
img.src = "img/player.png";

context.drawImage(img,0,0,310,212);
```

my plyer.png size is 312 *212 , the same size as canvas size.

However,my png file is expansioned on the canvas. Consequently, right edge and bottom edge protrude from the canvas.

Why my png doesn't fit in ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All canvas should have width and height attributes specified

```
<canvas width="310" height="212"></canvas>
```

Width and height shouldn't use 'px'.
With javascript use:

```
var c = document.querySelector('canvas');
c.width=310;
c.height=212;// as  Ken Fyrstenberg mentioned
```

Also be sure to wait till image will load.

```
img.onload(function(){
   //drawimage
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot somehow it works well. This is mysterious behavior of canvas though...

Comment: without that you would not be able to scale canvas. With this you can make "responsive canvas". by default I think is assigned to 300.

Comment: @MaciejPaprocki Yes, leave off the "px" when sizing inside the html canvas element. And yes, the canvas defaults to a size of 300 x 150 unless instructed otherwise.

Comment: This line `c-height` should be `c.height` (chew.. chew.. gets on the horse.. says "gentlemen", wanders off into the sunset)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the size as an attribute not styles. Try this:

```
 <canvas id="mainCanvas" width="310" height="212">
 </canvas>
```