# issue with resizing an image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to import an image inside a canvas but the resulting image as the wrong format (canvas and image should be 300x300 px).
How to force the canvas ans its image on these sizes?

```js
const createImage = (articleNumber, description, name, dateCreated, src) =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        canvas.style.width = '300px'
        canvas.style.height = '300px'
        // canvas.style.display = 'none'
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

        const imgBase = new Image()
        imgBase.src = 'http://makepixelart.com/pixelpixapp/celebs/kirk.PNG'

        imgBase.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(imgBase, 0, 0, 300, 300)
          ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
          ctx.font = 'bold 50px Arial'
          ctx.fillText(articleNumber, 475, 225)
          ctx.fillText(description, 475, 380)
          ctx.fillText(name, 475, 495)
          ctx.fillText(dateCreated, 475, 610)
          const imgFigure = new Image()
          imgFigure.src = src
          imgFigure.onload = () => {
            ctx.drawImage(imgFigure, 40, 130, 390, 470)
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL())
          }
        }
      })
    createImage('xyz', 'desc', 'name item', '20170101', 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3e/23/92/3e2392ecff7d230cc8ae82e462f2a690--pixel-art-templates-change-background.jpg').then(base64 => {
      console.log(base64)
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image size doesn't match the canvas size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28611849/image-size-doesnt-match-the-canvas-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const createImage = (articleNumber, description, name, dateCreated, src) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height = 300;
    // canvas.style.display = 'none'
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

    const imgBase = new Image()
    imgBase.src = 'http://makepixelart.com/pixelpixapp/celebs/kirk.PNG'

    imgBase.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(imgBase, 0, 0, 300, 300)
      ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
      ctx.font = 'bold 50px Arial'
      ctx.fillText(articleNumber, 475, 225)
      ctx.fillText(description, 475, 380)
      ctx.fillText(name, 475, 495)
      ctx.fillText(dateCreated, 475, 610)
      const imgFigure = new Image()
      imgFigure.src = src
      imgFigure.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(imgFigure, 40, 130, 390, 470)
        resolve(canvas.toDataURL())
      }
    }
  })
createImage('xyz', 'desc', 'name item', '20170101', 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3e/23/92/3e2392ecff7d230cc8ae82e462f2a690--pixel-art-templates-change-background.jpg').then(base64 => {
  console.log(base64)
})
```

set width and height of canvas using this

```
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
```

Answer (score 0):

This   resolve(canvas.toDataURL())   not work (Cross-domain security error)  . When you setup from canvas width and height no need for style. also no need for 'px' just :

```
    canvas.width = '300'
    canvas.height = '300'
```

```js
const createImage = (articleNumber, description, name, dateCreated, src) =>
      new Promise(resolve => {
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        canvas.width = '300'
        canvas.height = '300'
        // canvas.style.display = 'none'
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')

        const imgBase = new Image()
        imgBase.src = 'http://makepixelart.com/pixelpixapp/celebs/kirk.PNG'

        imgBase.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(imgBase, 0, 0, 300, 300)
          ctx.fillStyle = '#000000'
          ctx.font = 'bold 50px Arial'
          ctx.fillText(articleNumber, 475, 225)
          ctx.fillText(description, 475, 380)
          ctx.fillText(name, 475, 495)
          ctx.fillText(dateCreated, 475, 610)
          const imgFigure = new Image()
          imgFigure.src = src
          imgFigure.onload = () => {
            ctx.drawImage(imgFigure, 40, 130, 390, 470)
            resolve(canvas.toDataURL())
          }
        }
      })
    createImage('xyz', 'desc', 'name item', '20170101', 'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/3e/23/92/3e2392ecff7d230cc8ae82e462f2a690--pixel-art-templates-change-background.jpg').then(base64 => {
      console.log(base64)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned previously set the canvas size by using:

```
canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;
```

To set the size to 300 x 300 for the imported image call the second drawImage as following:

```
ctx.drawImage(imgFigure, 40, 130, 300, 300)
```